# how to display the selected check box value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to dispaly the selected check box value if i click on the print button

here is my code

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkbox()
{
    var bk=document.getElementById("bk").value;;
    var cer=document.getElementById("cr").value;
    document.writeln(" " + bk );
    document.write(" " + cer);    
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="bk" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br></br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cr" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car<br></br> 
     <input type="submit" value="   Print   " size="30" onClick="checkbox()">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

If I select Bike check box and click on print button, it should display the only Bike.

Comment: Your document.write and writeln will obliterate any HTML you already have.

Comment: If you are using `document.write` for debugging purposes, you might want to consider moving to use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/console.log) - it's much easier and doesn't affect your document.

Answer (score 3):

i have edited your code and modified according to your needs. please go through the code.

```
    <! DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkbox()
{
    var bk=document.getElementById("bk").checked;;
    var cer=document.getElementById("cr").checked;
    if(bk) document.writeln(" Bike");
    if(cer) document.write(" Car");   
return false;   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="bk" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br></br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cr" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car<br></br> 
     <input type="submit" value="   Print   " size="30" onClick="return checkbox();">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function would create an array with the values of each checked item inside your form:

```
function checkbox()
{
  var checked = [].reduce.call(document.forms[0].vehicle, function(current, item) {
    if (item.checked) {
      current.push(item.value);
    }
    return current;
  }, []);
  alert(checked);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/akikir/1/)

Here, `document.forms[0].vehicle` returns both checkboxes with the name `vehicle` inside your form; I'm using `document.forms[0]` because you didn't give the form a name :)

Answer (score 0):

heres ur code.. this should solve ur problem..

```
  <! DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkbox()
{
    var bk=document.getElementById("bk").checked;;
    var cer=document.getElementById("cr").checked;
    if(bk) document.writeln(" Bike");
    if(cer) document.write(" Car");   
return false;   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="bk" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br></br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cr" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car<br></br> 
     <input type="submit" value="   Print   " size="30" onClick="return checkbox();">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```