# How to print checkbox's tick mark of a HTML Form

Tags: html, css

How can i Print tick/select/checked mark of a checkbox which I've used in my HTML form.

Print means printer, not echo print or P tag print.

Any solution please ?

```
<form class="form-horizontal bucket-form" id="printableArea" method="get">
<div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-offset-9 col-xs-6">
            <div class="icheck minimal">                  
              <div class="3">
                <div class="checkbox single-row">
                  <label>New</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" >
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="4">
                <div class="checkbox single-row">
                  <label>Old</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" />

<script>
function printDiv(divName) {
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
 window.print();
 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: screenshot, crop and print

Comment: Any codes? JavaScript or something else.

Comment: Code Added, kindly check.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; my browser automatically prints a check mark in the checked checkboxes, and none in the unchecked ones. Yours doesn’t? Then you need to tell us which one. You want something else? Then describe what exactly.

Comment: Which browser you are using? My browser doesn't print checked checkboxes. I am attaching a screenshot here.

Comment: Image added... Kindly check now

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be, to change the value of 'checked' attribute.

Add a JS method to your script:

```
function isChecked(event){
    if(event.getAttribute('checked') === null){
        event.setAttribute('checked','');
    }
    else{
        event.removeAttribute('checked');
    }
}
```

and call this method on every checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="isChecked(this)">
```

This would work fine. You could replace all `type="checkbox"` with
 `type="checkbox" onclick="isChecked(this)"` in few seconds.

**Or** you could use this as another way:
[how to display the selected check box value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425257/how-to-display-the-selected-check-box-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you change your HTML slightly to put the `label` immediately after the `input` you can target it with some CSS in your print style sheet using the `:checked` pseudo-class:

eg:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

or even add some text:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  content: " (selected)";
}
```

Hope that helps